# VS2012: How do I browse the TFS repository?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

How do I browse the TFS repository in VS2012?

I've been through all the Team Explorer window options and can't find the one that open the window  to browse all the folders/projects in the TFS repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Team Explorer, select the "Home" button in the toolbar (or choose "Home" from the context menu), then choose "Source Control Explorer".

Answer (score 6):

(1) To browse the version control folders, select Menu **View**, **Other Windows** and then Source Control Explorer.

(2) To browse all team projects and teams within the connected Team Project Collection, select **Projects and My Teams** in Team Explorer.

(3) To include deleted folders and files for version control using Source Control Explorer, select **Tools**, **Source Control**, and ensure the **Show deleted items in Source Control Explorer** checkbox is selected under the **Visual Studio Team Foundation Server** node.

Answer (score 0):

I know where it is, but I can't remember the exact menu options. :(

But you connect to a TFS box, then you choose the projects (TFS projects not code projects) you are interested in. Given you have access, they'll then appear as top level items in the team explorer window.

I think it's Connect / Open From Source Control?? option under source control in the File menu.